Zhu Shijie's Simulatenous Equation Problem

Given the relations $2yz=z^{2}+xz$ and $2x+4y+4z=x(y^{2}+x-z)$ between the sides of a right angled triangle $x,y,z$ with $z$ being the hypotenuse. Find the value of $2x+2y$.

I found this problem whilst reading Zhu Shijie's biography (Chinese mathematician who developed methods on simultaneous equation).
So far, I deduced that $$\begin{cases} x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2} \\ 2yz=z^{2}+xz \\ 2x+4y+4z=x(y^{2}+x-z) \end{cases}$$
Thus forming equations like: $x^{2}+y^{2}=z(2y-x)$ and $4(y+z)=x((z-x)(x+z-1)-2)$
Is there any hint that I could use to proceed here?

you can divide out $z$  from the middle equation. So $2y = z+x.$   With $4x^2 + 4 y^2 = 4 z^2,$  then $4 x^2 + x^2 + 2 xz + z^2 = 4 z^2 $  So   $ 5 x^2 + 2 x z - 3 z^2= 0$  or $(x+z)(5x-3z)=0 $

Or plug $z=2y-x$ into the first equation, then you will get $x^2+y^2=(x-2y)^2$, hence $4x=3y$ and thus $z=5x/3$. Then use the last eqation to solve $x$.

Thanks! your idea led me to finding the roots of $16x^{2}-6x-126=0$ which gives $x=3 \implies y=4, z=5$
